# How to fetch initial data in Vue 3 with async await before rendering?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios

I'm just started learning Vue 3. I want to load some initial data from an API to populate some fields before the App component is loaded. I checked the [documentation][1] and it says that top-level `await` can be used inside `<script setup>` but must be used in combination with `Suspense` which is currently experimental. The `onMounted` lifecycle method does not support asynchronous callbacks. After some research, I came up with this solution:

```
const isLoading = ref(true);
const user = reactive({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: ''
});

async function prefetch() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(vars.restUrl);
    user.firstName = res.data.firstName;
    user.lastName = res.data.lastName;
    user.email = res.data.email;
    isLoading.value = true;
  } catch (error) {
    // do something
  }
}


onMounted(() => {
  prefetch()
});
```

This works as expected but I was wondering if there is a better way. In Svelte, for instance, the `onMount` lifecycle hook can execute `async` code:

```
onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/tutorial/api/album`);
    photos = await res.json();
})
```

Thanks
[1]: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

Comment: Use suspense. This is exactly what it's for. It's unclear why you treated "experimental" label as something not worth using, but it is. "onMounted lifecycle method does not support asynchronous callbacks." - your code does exactly this, with the exception that vue is able to handle errors from promises in hooks but it's not possible if you throw a promise away.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake. The `vars.restUrl` does not exist. Thanks bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never had problems writing async in onMounted() hook in Vue 3 like this:

```
onMounted(async () => {
   await prefetch()
});
```

Comment: You are right bro. The code works perfectly. It was my stupid mistake. The URL I provided does not exist. Thnks though for your time